# Dictionary of dataframes not saving all

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I've been trying to create a dictionary of data frames so I can store data coming from different files. I have one dataframe created in the following loop, and I would like to aggregate them to have each dataframe to the dictionary. I will have to join them later by the date.

```
d = {}
for num in range(3,14): 
  nodeName = "rgs" + str(num).zfill(2) #The key should be the nodeName
  # Bunch of stuff to get the data ...

  # Fill dataframe
  data = {'date':date_list, 'users':users_list}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
  df = df.dropna(subset=['users'])
  df['users'] = df['users'].astype(int)
  d = {nodeName:df} 

print d
```

The problem that I have is, if I print the dictionary out of the loop I only have one item, the last one.

```
{'rgs13':          date  users
0  2016-01-18      1
1  2016-01-19      1  
2  2016-01-20      1
3  2016-01-21      1
4  2016-01-22      1
5  2016-01-23      1
6  2016-01-24      0
```

But I can clearly see that I can generate all the dataframes without problems inside the loop. How can I make the dictionary to keep all the df's? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually I tested d[nodeName] = df before posting but it was not working because of the name. I solved it finally by just changing the name dict[nodeName] = df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the end you are re-defining `d`.

What you want is this:

```
d = {}
for num in range(3,14): 
  nodeName = "rgs" + str(num).zfill(2) #The key should be the nodeName
  # Bunch of stuff to get the data ...

  # Fill dataframe
  data = {'date':date_list, 'users':users_list}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
  df = df.dropna(subset=['users'])
  df['users'] = df['users'].astype(int)
  d[nodeName] = df 

print d
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `d = {nodeName:df}` use

```
d[nodeName] = df
```

Since this adds a key/value pair to `d` whereas `d = {nodeName:df}` *reassigns* `d` to a new dict (with only the one key/value pair). Doing that in a loop spells death to all the previous key/value pairs.

You may find Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) a useful read. It will give you the right mental model for thinking about the relationship between variable names and values, and help you see what statements modify values (e.g. `d[nodeName] = df`) versus reassign variable names (e.g. `d = {nodeName:df}`).